# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allennlp.common'

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, allennlp

I am getting this error while importing allennlp,

```
from allennlp.common.util import sanitize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allennlp.common'
(venv-kbs) administrator@NLR:~/aman/Project$ python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 00:00:00)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import allennlp
>>> from allennlp.common.util import sanitize
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allennlp.common'
```

My allennlp version is 0.2.1 and even trying to update to 0.4.1 it gives the same error.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Do check python version, Allennlp keeps pushing updates on regular period and thing works according to Python as well as Pytorch version.